# Setting / changing the default ("index") page in a LiftWeb app

Tags: lift

I've googled like crazy but can't find an answer to this.

How do I change the page displayed for `http://www.mydomain.com/`? (Right after the web app is created the page defaults to `index.html`. I'd like to change this!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't change it.

Lift converts the request for "/" to List("index").  Any "blank" part of the request path is converted into "index".  Thus, the "index.html" template will be used to serve "/index" and "/".

Comment: Ok, thanks. But using URL-rewriting it should be trivial, no?