# Lift simple SiteMap with page other than index.html on startup

Tags: scala, lift

Here's another Scala/Lift related question I'm stuck with at the moment.

I followed the ubiquitous chat app example over at http://simply.liftweb.net/index-Chapter-2.html#toc-Chapter-2, and everything is up and running. Now, I just want to embed another HTML page instead of the `index.html`, in `Boot.scala` `SiteMap` and all I see is the following message:

> The Requested URL / was not found on this server

So, to show you my effort, I'll show you the `SiteMap` definition in `Boot.scala`:

```
// Build SiteMap
def sitemap() = SiteMap(
  Menu("Home") / "index" :: // Simple menu form
  // Menu with special Link
  Menu(Loc("Static", Link(List("static"), true, "/static/index"), 
       "Static Content")) ::
  // Menu entries for the User management stuff
  User.sitemap :_*)

LiftRules.setSiteMapFunc(sitemap)
```

The `index.html` is located under the `webapp` folder, so that its path looks like `webapp/index.html`. Here's the content of `index.html`:

```
<div id="main" class="lift:surround?with=default;at=content">
<!-- the behavior of the div -->
<div class="lift:comet?type=Chat">
    Some chat messages
    <ul>
        <li>A message</li>
        <li class="clearable">Another message</li>
        <li class="clearable">A third message</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div>
    <form class="lift:form.ajax">
        <input class="lift:ChatIn" id="chat_in"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Say Something"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

All of this was made during the chat app example. Now I just wanted to show a simple `login.html` file instead of `index.html`, so I placed it under `webapp/login.html`. The content of this file is here:

```
<div id="loginContainer" class="lift:surround?with=default;at=content">
<!-- the behavior of the div -->
<div>
    <form class="lift:form.ajax">
        <div class="loginInputWrapper">
            <input type="text" class="txtLogin lift:LogIn" id="loginName"/>
        </div>
        <div class="loginInputWrapper">
            <input type="password" class="pwLogin lift:LogIn" />
        </div>
        <div class="buttonWrapper loginButtonWrapper">
            <button id="loginButton" class="hiddenButton qsbfont" type="submit">Login</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

and I adapted the `SiteMap` definition like this:

```
Menu("Home") / "login" :: // Simple menu form
```

This all seems to me as if it should run as smoothly as including the `index.html` on start up, but I'm seeing the mentioned message over and over again if I want to access the site. **Does anybody have an idea what's going on here and can give me a hint/solution for this?**

If it's of interest: I'm running the Scala WAR on Tomcat 7 from within Intellij IDEA Enterprise (Trial license)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525039/setting-changing-the-default-index-page-in-a-liftweb-app

Comment: thanks - I didn't see that question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`index.html` is the default page that is shown if `/` is requested. Why would you want to change that? Either rename `login.html` to `index.html` or use URL rewriting. However, the last option would only serve to confuse anyone who will be reading your source code.

The reason for the error message is that you requested `/` and (I assume) there is no entry for "index" in your `SiteMap`, so it doesn't know how to handle the request. It has no way to know that you wanted `login.html` to be the default page.

Comment: thanks, I'll consider that - I just wondered why it is not possible. And also, why Lift won't give me a proper error code, but the posted String...

Comment: thanks a lot @Kim Stebel, it seems that I was wrong in my understanding of `SiteMap`.